# Add/Delete class to <li> with Javascript when you are on specific div.

Tags: javascript, class, menu, navigation, addition

I open this thread to ask your help with JavaScript.

My website is divided vertically into four main div.

```
<div id="homepage"> Content </ div>
<div id="page1"> Content </ div>
<div id="page2"> Content </ div>
<div id="page3"> Content </ div>
<div id="page4"> Content </ div>
```

On the right of page there is navigation menu, div position: fixed.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#homepage"> Homepage </ a> </ li>
<li> <a href="#page1"> Page1 </ a> </ li>
<li> <a href="#page2"> Page2 </ a> </ li>
<li> <a href="#page3"> Page3 </ a> </ li>
<li> <a href="#page4"> page4 </ a> </ li>
</ ul>
</ div>
```

I wish that when you are in a div container (page1 or page2 etc) is added to a class corresponding menu item.

And 'possible to do this with javascript?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You will use the node tree for setting attribute. What i mean

```
var node = document.getElementById("dividname").getElementsByTagName("li")[i];
node.setAttribute("class", "classname");
```

for deleting the class just use above without any value

```
node.setAttribute("class", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

a simplest solution in jquery that comes to my mind would be something like:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function(){
 var divId = $(this).attr("href");
 $('.page-div').removeClass("special-class");
 $(divId).addClass("special-class");
});
```

please note that `.menu-link` is a class for your `<a>` inside `<li>` and `.page-div` is a class for divs with ids `page1`, `page2` etc.

Comment: But I would not have the event only if you click on the menu. The menu items should light up even if I use the scroll bar with the mouse.